Get the HMAC keys generated while creating docusign connect
I am using Docusign rest apis using java sdk library to create connect to listen to the events on my envelopes.
For security i would like to use HMAC enabled for all the connect events. I see there is an option to generate the HMAC Keys during connect creation api. But how to get these values so that when a request comes from docusign for me to verify that it is an valid request.
As per the API developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/… we can use includeHMAC property to generate the HMAC keys for this connect. How can I get the generated keys using the APIs itself?

Vineel, there's currently no public API or another means to generate HMAC keys programmatically.
The product team is aware of this need and is going to assess and prioritize a new capability to enable developers to create HMAC keys using an API endpoint.
The details or timeline is not something I can provide at this time.

As per the API developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/connect/… we can use includeHMAC property to generate the HMAC keys for this connect. How can I get the generated keys using the APIs itself

You cannot, its not supported in the API
